# Annotations from validate @notNull not working

Tags: java

when use @notNull ,it doesn't work

this is my code

```
import lombok.Data;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
@Data
public class MigrateRequestVo {
    @NotNull(message = "toCity不能为空")
    private Integer toCity;
    @NotNull (message = "楼盘Id不能为空")
    private Long[] resblockIds;
    private Integer bizcircleId;
    private Integer districtId;
}
```

When I try to use it in another class, validation doesn't work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resblock2City", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public Response migrateResblock2City( @Valid  MigrateRequestVo migrateRequestVo, BindingResult bindingResult){....}
```

Why doesn't this apply constraints for toCity and resblockIds? What else do I need to do?

Comment: Would it be @NonNull instead of @NotNull?

Comment: It should work fine. Are you sure you are not passing default values (0)?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `@Validated` on class level.

Comment: That's not the same and not needed for single usage of `@Valid`